# How to count items in Excel within a date range or without an end date

Tags: excel-formula

Note: date formats are DD/MM/YYYY

I have a list of records, each with one column for a start date, and one for an end date.

Every record has a start date, but if an item is current it has no end date and the end date cell is blank.

I want to write a/some formulas to determine how many records were a given age at a given date, rounded down to the nearest whole year.

So for example, how many records were 0-1 years old at the date at (cell reference R1), and then how many were 1-2 years, 2-3 years etc.

I want this to be reusable so that I can update the date at R1 each month and it recalculates automatically. This is easy enough for R1=TODAY, as I can assume all end dates are in the past, but for R1=EDATE(TODAY,-12) it becomes trickier.

As an example, in the yellow highlighted cell I want to calculate how many records were between 1&2 years old as of 30/06/21 (S1), AND were current at the time (i.e. exclude from the count any records that have an end date before 30/06/21).

The blue highlighted area is my data, the green area is what I'm trying to calculate. I don't mind adding an extra data column or two if it assists in the calculation, but I don't want to have to add an extra column for every year that I'm trying to calculate, if it can be avoided.

[image: screenshot of data]

| Start Date | End Date | Years (as of 30/06/2022) | Age | 30/06/2022 | 30/06/2021 | 30/06/2020 | 30/06/2019 | 30/06/2018 | 30/06/2017 | 30/06/2016 | 30/06/2015 | 30/06/2014 | 30/06/2013 |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20/09/2021 |  | 0.77 | 13 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 7/09/2020 | 4/12/2020 | 0.24 | 12 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 6/08/2019 |  | 2.90 | 11 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 17/02/2020 |  | 2.37 | 10 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1/04/2019 |  | 3.25 | 9 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 16/03/2020 | 18/11/2020 | 0.68 | 8 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 17/08/2021 | 19/11/2021 | 0.26 | 7 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 23/08/2022 |  | -0.15 | 6 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 16/11/2020 | 1/04/2022 | 1.37 | 5 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 20/04/2020 | 21/10/2021 | 1.50 | 4 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 7/05/2019 | 26/02/2021 | 1.81 | 3 | 2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 29/06/2020 | 7/01/2021 | 0.53 | 2 | 5 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 16/08/2021 | 20/04/2022 | 0.68 | 1 | 5 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  | 0 | 13 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Comment: It would be easier to help you, if you provide sample data as a table. Take a look at [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables). Also reading [repro] might help you

Comment: Thank you Ike, I am a very irregular user of this site, appreciate your assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a table for the data (insert table) --> tblData

```
=LET(calculatedAge,MAP(tblData[Start Date],tblData[End Date],
        LAMBDA(startdate,enddate,
             ROUNDDOWN((MIN(IF(ISBLANK(enddate),E$1,enddate),E$1)-startdate)/365,0))
              ),
filteredAges,FILTER(calculatedAge,calculatedAge=$D2),
IFERROR(ROWS(filteredAges),0))
```

The `MAP`-function returns the calculated age per target date (E$1) - rounded down.
It simulates a helper column - that then can be filtered.

Thanks to @Robert Mearns for the FILTER-hack - as COUNTIF doesn't work in this scenario (s. [Using LET with COUNTIF and Array, e.g. MAP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73063041/16578424))

[image]

Comment: Looks like actual wizardry but I think I understand what's happening. Thank you so much for your help.