# Using LET with COUNTIF and Array, e.g. MAP

Tags: excel-formula

***Edit: 2022-07-26***: found this web page that gives background **why** COUNTIF isn't working: https://exceljet.net/excels-racon-functions

**Original question:**

I like to compose a LET-function - based on a MAP-array - and then return the COUNTIF-values (see whole formula at the end of the question)

The **simplified** version of my problem is:

`=LET(figures,{1;10;13;10},COUNTIF(figures,10))` returns `#VALUE` instead of 2  (row 4 in screenshot)

Whereas e.g.
`=LET(figures,{1;10;13;10},ROWS(figures))` returns as expected 4  (row 2 in screenshot).

What works too:

`=LET(figures,{1;10;13;10},figures)`  (row 9 in screenshot)

`=COUNTIF(B9#,10)` returns 2 as expected (row 14 in screenshot)

**So the question is:**
How do I have to adjust `=LET(figures,{1;10;13;10},COUNTIF(figures,10))` to return the correct value of 2?

[image]

Further background:

I am trying to built an answer for [How to count items in Excel within a date range or without an end date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73060211/16578424).

What I would like to do is:

`=LET(calculatedAge,MAP(tblData[Start Date], tblData[End Date], LAMBDA(startdate,enddate,ROUND((MIN(IF(ISBLANK(enddate),H$1,enddate),H$1)-startdate)/365,0))), COUNTIF(calculatedAge,$G2))`

which returns the #VALUE error as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your formula is trying to return an array when **COUNTIF** is used.

Try using **FILTER** and then **ROW** in the **LET** function.

```
=LET(figures,{1;10;13;10},filtered,FILTER(figures,figures=10),ROWS(filtered))
```

And the full formula would be:

=LET(calculatedAge,MAP(tblData[Start Date], tblData[End Date],
LAMBDA(startdate,enddate,ROUND((MIN(IF(ISBLANK(enddate),H$1,enddate),H$1)-
startdate)/365,0))),filtered,FILTER(calculatedAge,calculatedAge=$G2),
ROWS(filtered))

Comment: Great - that did it - except that I need an IFERROR for the `ROWS` in case `filtered` is not calculated (using 0 as if-empty-value doesn't work as that would be returned as 1 row)

Comment: see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73063580/16578424

Comment: You can add an IFERROR to return zero if the ROWS fails due to nothing being reurned by the filter.  `=LET(figures,{1;10;13;10},filtered,FILTER(figures,figures=11),IFERROR(ROWS(filtered),0))`

Comment: that's what I have done :-)